# Access link local address using c

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am working on a IPv6 network application, built using C.

Now as per my requirements, I need to fill default address of my packet with link local address of system.

Is there any function/library avaliable in `glibc` for the purpose.

I know I can do this using `system` command and running a script that can access `ifcfg-eth0` from system but I guess that would not be advisible.

I am new to all this socket stuff so please excuse if missing something trivial.

**Edit :**

OS : linux

and this is actually an open source implementation `sendip` built using raw C socket programming. Now, I am modifying it acc. to my requirements.

http://snad.ncsl.nist.gov/ipv6/sendip.html

Comment: How is this related to `kernel`?

Comment: Can we have more info about your OS / IPv6 library ?

Comment: What you need is just bind your socket to a certain IP?

Comment: Again, it seems like it is a user-space program. You are also talking about `system` and `glibc`. If you are not writing a kernel module, you should remove the `linux-kernel` tag. Since any answer, telling you to use `<some_function>` would be wildly different if the function is for user or kernel space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out ..... 
Actually I did not, this blog is the one which actually helped me out.
I am very thankful to him for his advice.

http://valileo-valilei.blogspot.in/2010/09/getting-link-local-addres-from.html

Here is a implementation : (I am providing code here as it may help many others who may stuck in similar situation)

**Code:**

```
 #include "sys/types.h"
 #include "ifaddrs.h"
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <malloc.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int get_link_local_addr(char* if_name, int if_name_length, 
                      struct sockaddr_in6 *ip) {

    struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;
    int ret = -2;

    if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1) {
            perror("getifaddrs");
            ret = -1;
            freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
            return ret;
    }

    for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
            if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family != AF_INET6) continue;

            if (strncmp(ifa->ifa_name, if_name, if_name_length)) continue;

            struct sockaddr_in6 *current_addr =
                                    (struct sockaddr_in6 *) ifa->ifa_addr;

            if (!IN6_IS_ADDR_LINKLOCAL(&(current_addr->sin6_addr))) continue;

            memcpy(ip, current_addr, sizeof(*current_addr));
            ret = 0;
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
    return ret;
  }


  int main() {

  struct sockaddr_in6 *sa=(struct sockaddr_in6 *)malloc(40);
  char *src,dst[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

  get_link_local_addr("wlan0",5,sa);

  inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(sa->sin6_addr), dst, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

  printf("Link Layer Address is : %s\n",dst);

  return 0;

 }
```

**Output:**

`Link Layer Address is : fe80::d2df:9aff:fe56:917d`

**Cross-Check on command line :**

```
  $ ifconfig wlan0
  wlan0
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:df:9a:56:91:7d  
      inet addr:172.31.9.171  Bcast:172.31.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: 2001:df0:92:0:d2df:9aff:fe56:917d/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::d2df:9aff:fe56:917d/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2001:df0:92:0:50df:d286:a281:e6c0/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:217235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:21173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:31550379 (31.5 MB)  TX bytes:4062945 (4.0 MB)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a IPv6 app, then you have a IPv6 API (socket or something).

This API should have a feature for getting the link local address of your system.

Beware of multi-homing.